# In a custom module, is there a way to allow all permissions for files/directories?

Tags: selinux

I've written a custom selinux module that looks something like this:

```
require {
    type my_app_t;
    type my_app_file_t;
    class file { getattr lock open read write execute execute_no_trans ioctl append setattr };
    class dir { write search getattr };
}

allow my_app_t my_app_file_t:file { append setattr write getattr execute read open execute_no_trans lock ioctl};
allow my_app_t my_app_file_t:dir { write search getattr};
```

This mostly works OK, but I'm tired of adding new perms every time a new deny shows up in audit.log.  Is there any way to just allow all permissions for files/directories with a given context?  For instance:

```
require {
    type my_app_t;
    type my_app_file_t;
    class file { * };
    class dir { * };
}

allow my_app_t my_app_file_t:file { * };
allow my_app_t my_app_file_t:dir { * };
```

Comment: `allow my_app_t my_app_file_t:file *;` works for me without the curly braces.

Comment: @NReilingh I'll keep experimenting with that, but I don't think it works.  I added this to my module: `allow nrpe_t user_tmp_t:dir *;`, but I'm still seeing this denial in my audit.log: `type=AVC msg=audit(1563901989.705:1826): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=8228 comm="stat" name="kitchen" dev="tmpfs" ino=29034 scontext=system_u:system_r:nrpe_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0`

Comment: @NReilingh do you have documentation for that syntax?  I'm struggling to find documentation to support your claim.  The modules do compile with the asterix though, so it seems to at least be valid syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using reference policy macros. Using reference policy macros, you can then use `manage_files_pattern` macro to allow all access, for example:

```
manage_files_pattern(my_app_t, my_app_file_t, my_app_file_t)
```

There are also [macros](https://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_RefPolicy#Reference_Policy_Support_Macros) for other commonly used patterns, located at [`/policy/support`](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/refpolicy/tree/master/policy/support) in the reference policy source.

If `my_app_t` is defined by a reference policy module, there likely already exists an interface, which you can use to allow access. Interfaces are documented in reference policy API documentation (provided by `selinux-policy-doc` package) and are also available [online](http://oss.tresys.com/docs/refpolicy/api/) (however a bit outdated).

The easiest way to build a reference policy module is by using the makefile in SELinux policy development package (`selinux-policy-devel` or similar) of your distribution, for example: `make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile my_app.pp`.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know the `manage_files_pattern` macro existed.  In my particular case, `my_app_t` and `my_app_file_t` are actually defined in my module, I just didn't include them in my question because it didn't seem relevant.